# php echo remove slashes from url

Tags: php, url, joomla

I have experienced a strange problem with the slideshow on our corporate site and i haven't figured what is whong. After Joomla updated to 3.7.2 in place where php echo the url i have the following:

**Instead of:**

```
style="background-image: url("images/sliders/slide-1.jpg");
```

**It outputs:**

```
style="background-image: url(" images sliders slide-1.jpg");
```

The script for the slideshow has the following Vars:

```
$ctaImg = $helper->get('img');

$ctaBackground  = 'background-image: url("'.$ctaImg.'"); background-attachment: fixed; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;';
```

and the line that applies the img on background-image url is:

```
<div class="acm-cta style-5 <?php echo $helper->get('style'); ?> <?php if($ctaImg): echo 'bg-image-large'; endif; ?>" <?php if($ctaImg): echo 'style="'.$ctaBackground.'"'; endif; ?> >
```

Using var-dump i have the following output:

```
<!-- Var1: string(33) "images/sliders/slide-1.jpg"
 Var2: string(143) "background-image: url("images/sliders/slide-1.jpg"); background-attachment: fixed; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;"
 -->
```

Elements:

[image: screenshot - Elements]

Sources:

[image: screenshot - Sources]

In Developer Tools in Chrome at Elements tab, slashes are missing from url but in Sources the url is correct. It drives me crazy....

Comment: look at the change notes in latest joomla update and see if they did anything with the function that provide this output

Comment: I take a look at change notes but i can't find any info regarding. The problem is that i don't remember from which version i updated from (3.6 probably)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To fix that you just need to remove quotes from background-image: url("")

In inspector your code looks:

```
style="background-image: url("/images/sliders/slide-1.jpg");"
```

and should

```
style="background-image: url(/images/sliders/slide-1.jpg);
```